# Testing Spring MVC: Null view when using standaloneSetup()

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf, spring-test-mvc

I cannot get spring mvc test framework to run correctly in standaloneSetup configuration, it always result in a null View. i am using thymeleaf as the view technology in a spring boot v1.2.7 application.

It works fine in a full environment : webAppContextSetup

Here is my setup method

```
@Before
public void setup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
            .standaloneSetup(brandsController)
            .setCustomArgumentResolvers(new PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver())
            .build();
}
```

I tried to add a view resolver with no success, it results in a NullPointerException as the view is null.

```
@Before
public void setup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
            .standaloneSetup(brandsController)
            .setCustomArgumentResolvers(new PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver())
            .setViewResolvers(new ThymeleafViewResolver())
            .build();
}
```

The exception

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet.service(TestDispatcherServlet.java:65)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain$ServletFilterProxy.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:167)
at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:134)
at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc.perform(MockMvc.java:156)
at org.commerceforge.estore.tests.mvc.web.unit.BrandsControllerTests.testBrandsIndexPage(BrandsControllerTests.java:90)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:254)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:193)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:117)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:202)
at org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:190)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1244)
at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet.render(TestDispatcherServlet.java:105)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1027)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:971)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
```

the test:

```
@Test
public void testBrandsIndexPage() throws Exception {
    when(brandService.findAll(any(Store.class), any(Pageable.class))).thenReturn(Builders.Brands.buildPage(10));

    this.mockMvc.perform(get("/brands"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(view().name("brands/index"))
            .andExpect(model().attribute("brands", instanceOf(Page.class)))
            .andDo(print())
            .andReturn()
            //.andExpect(content().string(containsString("Brands list")))
    ;

}
```

This test run fine, it only fails when i uncomment the last line which test the content of the response as the view is null

the print method produces:

```
ModelAndView:
    View name = brands/index
         View = null
    Attribute = store
        value = Id: null, Name: null
       errors = []
    Attribute = brands
        value = Page 0 of 1 containing org.commerceforge.estore.app.model.Brand instances
       errors = []
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: doesn't `ThymeleafViewResolver` need an `SpringTemplateEngine` and this needs a `ServletContextTemplateResolver` plus other parameters setting up ?  This configures where the thymeleaf markup templates are, what add-ins (dialects) you have, etc...  As per http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/thymeleafspring.html

Comment: Dump the output seen, you might find it still has thymeleaf markup (untransformed) in the output because the engine never processed it, hence `"Brands list"` is not in the output as thymeleaf processing would cause this to be emitted, instead of template markup.

Comment: The problem is not the unconfigured ViewResolver, the problem is that there is no view instance passed to it !! the view is null, that's clear from the test print() method output...  the line .setViewResolvers(new ThymeleafViewResolver()) confirms that as it results in a NullPointerException because view is null. Also none of the examples nor the reference documentation require to configure a viewresolver. thanks

Comment: But ThymeleafViewResolver can return null, i.e. not resolve any view when the engine is not setup and doesn't know how to find the thymeleaf  markup files.  http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.thymeleaf/thymeleaf-spring3/2.0.11/org/thymeleaf/spring3/view/ThymeleafViewResolver.java#608  ... enable TRACE output logging?  .. ViewResolver can return null to allow resolver chaining.

Comment: It is not returning null, it throws a NullPointerException. :)

Comment: So post the Exception!

Comment: Ok, i posted it, Hope this will help. :)

Comment: http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.thymeleaf/thymeleaf-spring4/2.1.2.RELEASE/org/thymeleaf/spring4/view/ThymeleafView.java#202  so this is the line ?  `if (!viewTemplateEngine.isInitialized()) {` ... I referr you to my original and 1st comment in this SO question. :)  you did not setup the Engine it is null!

Comment: Even if i intialized it, the view is still null ! this is the problem, the view instance is null, the problem is not related to the templateEngine in the first place. configuring a template engine and view resolver are not required, all the examples and reference documentation lack this step.

Comment: Ok, please cite references to "all the examples and reference documentation" you are working from.  Google does not return much for the search `"setViewResolvers(new ThymeleafViewResolver())"`

Comment: This is the point, the test should run without this line of code altogether, it is not required to set a viewResolver, the examples do not provide one yet they work fine, it is not required at all.

Comment: If you use `MockMvcBuilders.webappContextSetup(new FixupNameOfClass())` causing a slower unit test, does it then work ?  If so post your controller class (and the base example you are working from).